# Is method A really better than method B?

Tags: statistics, binomial-distribution, hypothesis-testing

Suppose I have two methods, method A and method B. We evaluate the performance of these algorithms in 100 consecutive experiments with either positive (1) or negative outcome (0).

Method A achieves 84 positive outcomes and method B achieves 56 positive outcomes.

Is there measure that sort of tells us how sure we can be that A didn't perform better by chance?

My idea would be the following:

Fit a binomial distribution to the results produced in A (ML estimate). Than calculate the likelihood of the results of B being produced by that distribution ... although I don't really know how that is done.

Are there any suggestions to how to retrieve a really meaningful statement concerning whether A is not just by chance better than B?

Am I on th right track?

Comment: Well...suppose this were chance.  The binomial would have total sample mean of $70$ (the average), so $p=.7$.  Using the normal approximation that would give $\sigma =\sqrt {100\times .7 \times .3}\approx 4.58$ for a sample of size $100$ Thus sample rates of $56$ or $84$ would each be $3\sigma $ events.  Very low probability indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, right general track. But I don't think you need to derive the test
using ML; most texts show a test with a normal and/or chi-squared test
statistic. Can't be sure about those details without knowing more about
what you have been studying lately. The Comment by @lulu suggests the two
methods are not the same. I agree, here are two (similar) formal tests.

First, see [*test comparing 2 binomial proportions*](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/software/dataplot/refman1/auxillar/binotest.htm) for the equations and theory. (Or look in your textbook.)

Second, here is Minitab output for your data, which indicates you should
reject $H_0: p_A = p_B.$

```
Test and CI for Two Proportions 

Sample   X    N  Sample p
1       84  100  0.840000
2       56  100  0.560000

Difference = p (1) - p (2)
Estimate for difference:  0.28
95% CI for difference:  (0.159053, 0.400947)
Test for difference = 0 (vs ≠ 0):  Z = 4.32  P-Value = 0.000
```

From R statistical software, a somewhat similar chi-squared test looks is shown
below, also rejecting the null hypothesis. (Your text may show this test instead of the one above, or addition to it.)

```
MAT = matrix(c(84, 56, 16, 44), nrow=2)
MAT
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   84   16
[2,]   56   44

prop.test(MAT)

    2-sample test for equality of proportions with continuity correction

data:  MAT
X-squared = 17.357, df = 1, p-value = 3.097e-05
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.1490526 0.4109474
sample estimates:
prop 1 prop 2 
  0.84   0.56
```

*Note:* $\sqrt{17.365} = 4.167133 \approx 4.32$ from Minitab.
I think the main difference is that R uses a 'continuity correction'.